# Cannot select items in mysql with "WHERE s_id IN ($array)"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, where-clause

Here is my problem, i have two tables, in one are conections (one column - team id, other  - persons id) i find all the persons id's from an exact team (here it is 't1') and put it into an array, everything is ok here.

```
$id1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM connections WHERE team='t1'");
$id11 = array();
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($id1))) {
    $id11[] = $row;
}

echo "";
print_r($id11);
echo "";
```

until here everything is ok, in print_r i see items of an array, that i want to see. But from here [fecal matter] happens. I vant to select person names from 'persons' table, that has id's from previous array ($id11). at the end i get an empty array.

```
$kom1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM persons WHERE s_id IN('".join("','", $id11)."')");


//$kom1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM persons WHERE s_id IN(".implode(',',$id11).')'); //this one doesnt work too
$kom11 = array();
while(($row1 =  mysql_fetch_assoc($kom1))) {
$kom11[] = $row1;
}

echo "";
print_r($kom11);
echo "";
```

Tried everything, please help me,thank you.

Comment: What does the SQL look like when you echo it out? Does it work when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: Keep the language clean. there is absolutely NO reason to use that kinda of wording here. Plus you have no error handling - are you sure that query is executing correctly? `$row1 = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`. Fix up your variable names as well. `$kom1` and `$kom11` are just going to lead to major confusion later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery directly in second query :

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE boing IN (SELECT id FROM blah2 WHERE team=1337)
```

Should be working in every not so fancy DB

Comment: Thank you, your way and explanation was the best!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$id11[] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: given the OP isn't even selecting an `id` field in the query, this is flat out wrong.

Comment: @MarcB - this is correct; he's referring to the 4th line of code

Comment: SELECT id FROM connections WHERE team='t1 - for the blind man @Mark B

Comment: You're right. my apologies. I was looking at the second block of code.

Comment: `SELECT P.name FROM persons p, connections c WHERE p.s_id = c.id and c.team = 't1'`

Answer (score 1):

My question is: why are you doing this with two queries in the first place?

You can simply use:

```
select p.name from persons p, connections c
where c.team = 't1'
and c.id = p.s_id
```

(or the equivalent explicit join).

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, minus using an implicit syntax.